# How to check Time between 2 Dates

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have 2 params (`java.util.Date`) and I need check if my current time is between this 2 dates. For this I need ignore my date and just check my time.

I need ignore `yyyy/MM/dd` and just check my `hh:mm:ss`. For example:

```
Date 1: 2008/11/10 08:05:55
Date 2: 2010/12/11 10:12:33
Current Date: 2020:09:29 09:12:13
```

I need check `Date 1 <= Current Date <= Date 2`

But I need check just `hh:mm:ss` like:

```
08:05:55 <= 09:12:13 <= 10:12:33 = True
```

Ignoring the  `yyyy/MM/dd`

Comment: Please add your code how to tried to achieve your aim.

Comment: Just convert all three to `String`s using a 24-hour time format like `HHmmss`, then compare the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest converting to Java 8 time API objects and using their intuitive methods.

Here's some utility methods I've put together for you use:

```
public static boolean nowIsBetweenInclusive(Date start, Date end) {
  return timeIsBetweenInclusive(LocalTime.now(), asLocalTime(start), asLocalTime(end));
}

public static LocalTime asLocalTime(@NonNull Date date) {
  return date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalTime();
}

public static boolean timeIsBetweenInclusive(@NotNull LocalTime time, LocalTime start, LocalTime end) {
  return start != null && end != null && !time.isBefore(start) && !time.isAfter(end);
}
```